# Coiling ac wire around iron rod bad or good?

Tags: heat, wire, flux

I have around 4-5 meter excess wire length on extension board to power my computer. Power consumption is around max 500 watt.

I know there are probably 2 more thread on same topic.

But they mostly talk about heat because they are coiling around non conductive material.

As iron is more thermaly conductive than air, I think heat won't be an issue. Let me know if it is

The main part I am concerned about is coiling good or bad.

I know coiling AC wire creates some kind of flux ( I don't have any experties in electrical)

I want to ask whether it **will affect my electricity bill?**

Also **is there any danger of electric shocked if I touch my table?** ( Wire is coiled around table metallic leg.)

Comment: There is no good reason I can think of to wrap the wire around a steel leg. Nothing good will come of it. It could increase your electrical usage very slightly.

Comment: How does electrical usage will increase?

Comment: Induces eddy currents

Comment: If you can't get a cable of the correct length, I suggest [winding it in a figure-of-8](https://youtu.be/FBtIXy8I97s?t=92). Hold the coils together with a cable tie, wire tie, or string. Attach loosely to something if desired.

Comment: After thinking about it more, I really doubt it will have any effect at all on your electric bill. Nothing good will come of it, but nothing bad will come of it either. So you should use some other criteria (not electrical engineering) to decide what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heat could still be an issue. The main problem with wrapping wire around something is that you are decreasing the surface area. This leads to increased temperatures. However, if the cable is thick enough and the current is not too high, the temperature rise should be acceptable. I would guess that powering a 500W power supply from mains voltage in the described setup should be fine. To be safe, check if the cables are getting hot under full load.

Another point to consider is that you are building an inductor by wrapping wire around an Iron rod. The inductance is roughly twice as high compared to wrapping it around a non-magnetic material. But in your case with 5 m of wire, the inductance will still be quite low and will not have any meaningful effect at mains frequency.

Wrapping the wire around the metal rod will not affect your electrical bill in a noticeable way.

If the insulation of the wire is intact, there should be no risk of electric shock. I would still suggest looking for a shorter wire and not wrapping it around the metallic table leg, even if it is only safety relevant in unlikely scenarios.

Comment: "*... you are building an inductor by wrapping wire around an Iron rod.*" I wonder? The L and N currents will be in opposite directions and any induction will completely cancel out.

Comment: Good call. I guess it depends on the phase of the currents. You could also think of this as two coupled inductors. Ultimately, inductance is not the Main issue in the application.

Comment: It's basically a common mode choke, which is nothing bad.